dealing with an image that is a bit heavy in size and has a width of 100%
I'm using bootstrap and i have an image inside col, the image takes a width of 100% to fit the parent, but the image is a bit heavy and doesn't need to be downloaded in full size when shown for example on mobile devices, how can i use sizes property to reduce image size on devices that show less size of the image if the image has dynamic width?
      <div">
        <div className="col-md-5 col-lg-4">
          <Image
            src={...}
            sizes="100vw"
            className={`${styles.amenitiesImg} w-100`}
            style={{min-height:"400px"}}
            placeholder="blur"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
          <h3>...</h3>
          <p>
            ...
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

